# usetimestamp has no effect when using ant GET task?

Tags: ant, get, nexus

I am trying a GET from ant but the problem if I invoke it twice, the file is downloaded twice, it should download only once because I have set the usetimestamp to true, what could be the issue?

This is the ant get command I am using:

```
<get src="..." dest="..."  verbose="true" usetimestamp="true" />
```

This is part of the log that I got:

```
[get] last modified = Wed May 17 10:51:19 EEST 2017
```

Comment: Is the "last modified" time different every time `<get>` runs?

Comment: no it is the same each time

Comment: Ant should have logged a line with "local file date" as well. What does it say?

Comment: I didn't get any log that provides the local file date, should I send any additional parameter?

Comment: Is the value passed to the `dest` attribute different every time `<get>` runs?

Answer (score 0):

sorry all I found the solution to my issue, the problem is that I had another line of code that is deleting the directory before calling the ant GET. Once I removed this line of code, the usetimestamp flag worked flawlessly.